# Elsevier "Computers & Security" journal latex template

Tags: publications, paper-submission, elsevier

I am trying to target the [Computers & Security](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/computers-and-security) journal to publish my research. I opened the journal's page but I didn't find the latex template that is used in the journal such as [this paper's template](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0167404815001388/1-s2.0-S0167404815001388-main.pdf?_tid=d15fcded-4465-479e-8868-f43da96b301b&acdnat=1533998254_a58c45bd211cd22bf555d5e2043ec462). I searched for a template and I found  [this one](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/elsevier) but it seems an old template and it also different than what is used in the papers published in it. Please where can I find such template?

Comment: Contact the editors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a specific template to submit your paper to this journal.

https://www.elsevier.com/journals/computers-and-security/0167-4048/guide-for-authors

> As part of the Your Paper Your Way service, you may choose to submit your manuscript as a single file to be used in the refereeing process. This can be a PDF file or a Word document, **in any format or lay-out that can be used by referees to evaluate your manuscript**.

So any generic format would be fine, e.g. the basic LaTeX `article` class.  If your paper is accepted, either you or they will redo the formatting for publication, and they'll give you the correct template if necessary.  But there is no point spending any time on that now.